# pgfplots plotting an expression which has a jump

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot the following expression: (x-1)/(x+2)

However if I add this in pgfplot as an expression, I get this result:
[image: Wrong pgfplot]

I would like to make the part in the middle disappear, since the function jumps at x=-2. It should look like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this? Currently I am using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            legend entries={$\frac{1-x}{x+2}$},
            legend style={at={(0.17, 1)}, anchor=north},
            every axis plot/.append style={thick}
            ]
            \addplot [mark=none, blue, samples=1000, unbounded coords = jump] expression {(x-1)/(x+2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I have already tried splitting the function in two domains, but this does not work somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Restricting the y axes did the trick for me:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid,
            xlabel={$x$},
            ylabel={$y$},
            legend entries={$\frac{1-x}{x+2}$},
            every axis plot/.append style={thick},
            restrict y to domain=-500:500
            ]
            \addplot [mark=none, blue, samples=1000] expression {(x-1)/(x+2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```