# Pgfplots domain exceptions

Tags: pgfplots

How can you disconnect "1/-0" and "1/0"

```
 \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines = middle, ymin = -10, ymax = 10, xmin = -5, xmax = 5]
          \addplot[color=red, samples = 100, domain=-5:5]{x^-1}
          node[right, pos=0.9]{$f(x)$};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you get a plot that extends all the way to `-5` with `domain=0:5`?

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571068/47927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle, 
    restrict y to domain=-30:30,   % <---
    ymin = -10, ymax = 10, 
    xmin = -5, xmax = 5,
    domain=-5:5,
    samples=101, no marks          % <---
    ]
\addplot {x^-1}    node[right, pos=0.9]{$f(x)$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow, in your picture the plot still shows around *x* = 0, probably due to a rounding error. But your solution works with `samples=101`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, you are right. I forgot on this (than number of sample should be odd number) at selecting number of samples ..... Corrected now.